# Pass dynamic tab number in jmeter

Tags: testing, automated-tests, jmeter

While recording steps using jmeter, i get a sample like '/setTabNumber.do?tabNum=2'. But, 2 is dynamic. It may be 3,4,6 etc on each login. How, to get this tabNum and pass it to the path.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just a random number in a specific range JMeter provides following functions:

- [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) - for generation of a random number in a range
- [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) - for generation of a random string from specified character set and specified length.

If tab number is something which can be found in the previous page source code you may have to get it with [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) (or similar) Post Processor

If your test case is more complex and you need to check i.e. *whether virtual user be redirected to correct tab on second attempt of opening login page* or so you may need to add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to your test plan.